# Why does not the event pass?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, web, react-native

Why does not alert ("onEnded") work? All like doing on the manual.

How to launch it in PlayerContainer?

```js
var PLAYER_ID = 'player';
var Player = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        document.getElementById(PLAYER_ID).addEventListener( 'ended', this.onEnded )
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        document.getElementById(PLAYER_ID).removeEventListener( 'ended', this.onEnded )
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <video
                id={PLAYER_ID}
                src={this.props.src}
            </video>
        )
    }
});
var PlayerContainer = React.createClass({
    onEnded: function () {
        alert("onEnded")
    },
    render: function() {
        return <Player
            src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"/>
    }
});
React.render(
    <PlayerContainer />,
    document.body
);
```

How to fix it?

Sorry for the stupid question. I study React.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in `this.onEnded` refers to `Player` instance not `PlayerContainer` instance, and `Player` doesn't have `onEnded` method, Try this:

```js
var PLAYER_ID = 'player';
var Player = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        document.getElementById(PLAYER_ID).addEventListener( 'ended', this.props.onEnded )
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        document.getElementById(PLAYER_ID).removeEventListener( 'ended', this.props.onEnded )
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <video
                id={PLAYER_ID}
                src={this.props.src}
            </video>
        )
    }
});
var PlayerContainer = React.createClass({
    onEnded: function () {
        alert("onEnded")
    },
    render: function() {
        return <Player
            src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
            onEnded={this.onEnded}/>
    }
});
React.render(
    <PlayerContainer />,
    document.body
);
```

Comment: Although this may work, this is not the recommended way to do it with react. There is no reason to manually attach event listeners to DOM elements since react already provides callbacks for this on DOM elements. Whenever you find yourself accessing the DOM by `document.getElementByID()` inside a react component this is in 99.99% of the cases (including this case) not the best thing to do. There are `refs` if you need a reference to the DOM element (e.g. in forms) and `<video>` provides the `onEnded` callback.

Comment: @trixn you're right about `onEnded`, but that wasn't the op's question. I solved his problem with React's recommended method and left unrelated stuff untouched.

Comment: Okay then let my say it differently. This is very very bad practice and you should never handle events like this in a react driven application. I don't like seeing this kind of bad practice as the accepted solution without any comment when the correct way to do it is even easier. And obviously OP didn't even do the react tutorial because this is extensively covered there. His correct question should have been "How do i handle events in react?"

Answer (score 0):

When creating react apps you should avoid accessing the DOM yourself. React provides callbacks for events on html elements. You need to pass the callback to your `video` component via props:

```
var Player = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <video
                id={PLAYER_ID}
                src={this.props.src}
                // pass the callback provided in the props to your video element
                onEnded={this.props.onEnded}
            />
        )
    }
});
var PlayerContainer = React.createClass({
    onEnded: function () {
        alert("onEnded")
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <Player
                src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" 
                // pass the callback to your Player component so that it will have it in it's props
                onEnded={this.onEnded}
            />
        );
    }
});
React.render(
    <PlayerContainer />,
    document.body
);
```

Also if you are new to react i recommend you to use it with ES6 syntax and to do the [very good tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html) which also uses ES6.

The same components in ES6 syntax:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const Player = ({src, onEnded}) => (
    <video src={src} onEnded={onEnded} />
);

class PlayerContainer extends Component {
    onEnded = () => {
        alert("onEnded");
    }

    render() {
        return (
             <Player
                 src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" 
                 onEnded={this.onEnded}
             />
        );
    }
}

React.render(
    <PlayerContainer />,
    document.body
);
```

Hint: The `<video>` element has no body.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `onEnded` as a props from `PlayerContainer` to `Player`, so in `PlayerContainer` you have to call `this.props.onEnded` instead of `this.onEnded`

I reproduced this scenario, check this out:

https://codepen.io/henriquebertoldi/pen/awRmzb